# Getting an error while trying to integrate slack in my django app?

Tags: python, django, slack, slack-api

Actually my requirement is integrating slack in my existing django app
for that I had done these following steps

1. I had created slack app in api.slack.com
2. I had followed this django package tutorial https://pypi.org/project/django-slack-oauth/
3. so I had included the getting slack button like this in my template
   like this `<a href='{% url 'slack_auth' %}'>Get slacked</a>`
   and when I click this the error in my webpage is

> ```
> Something went wrong when authorizing this app.
> Try going back and authorizing again. If problems persist, contact support for help.
>
> Error details
> Invalid client_id parameter
> ```

and the url of the page it is redirecting when I click getting slack is this https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=None&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fslack%2Flogin%2F&scope=admin%2Cbot&state=791cc2&tracked=1

Can anyone help me out from this?

I had included this https://slack.com/oauth/authorize in redirect urls section when I created an app

Can you say how to include the client_id redirect_uri scope state in the url

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Would be awesome if you could add the relevant part of your source to your question, so people can help you find the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Erik when I clicked the getting slack button it should redirect to slack and should authenticate that is what I am trying to do but invalid client_id parameter is the error I am getting but I had included the correct one in my settings.py file can you please help me

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I am asking should I need to include this client id in the redirect URL if yes how ? Thanks!

Comment: You must include your client ID in the redirect URL as described here: https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2#overview

Comment: You find the client ID for your app on the app management page where you have created your Slack app

Comment: @ErikKalkoken when I click this add to slack button as mentioned in the doc I am not getting any code in even it is not taking me to the redirect_url back

Comment: Alright. Please add you code to the question. It is nearly impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: Kindly guide me on how to deploy access token of slack in django @ErikKalkoken

Comment: Actually I didn't wrote any code I just got an access token where to specify this and how to specify this access token in my django project @ErikKalkoken

Comment: You need logic to run through the OAuth process and get an access token

Comment: Yes I got an access token now where to specify and how to use it is I am confusing can you guide me with a tutorial @ErikKalkoken

Comment: I would suggest to use the official Python library for Slack. Also has a lot of examples: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient

Comment: @ErikKalkoken thankyou for guiding me if you give it as a answer I can upvote and please help me is there any method to get only user names from the team from users.list method I am getting all the other stuff which is not necessary for me please help me I cant ask a new question

Comment: Yes, please open a new question if you have a new topic. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I am not given chance to open a new question can you please help me